# Find out number of orders & order value per customer in first 3 days of their joining?

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is a sample dataset:

```
user_id  first_payment_date  order_date  order_id   order_value
1         01/01/19           02/01/19      1          10
1         01/01/19           03/01/19      2          20
1         01/01/19           07/01/19      3          30
2         15/01/19           17/01/19      4          50
2         15/01/19           17/01/19      5          60
2         15/01/19           20/01/19      6          70
```

I am trying to find out number of orders & order value per customer within first 3 days of **first_payment_date**. Output would look like below:

```
user_id orders  order_value
1          2    30
2          2    110
```

I am looking for a solution in r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(2:3, list(~ as.Date(., format = "%d/%m/%y"))) %>%
 mutate(cond = as.numeric(order_date - first_payment_date) <= 3) %>%
 filter(cond) %>%
 group_by(user_id) %>%
 summarise(orders = n(),
           order_value = sum(order_value))

  user_id orders order_value
    <int>  <int>       <int>
1       1      2          30
2       2      2         110
```